# Data stored is overwritten everytime i do a new transaction

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust

use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
entrypoint,
entrypoint::ProgramResult,
msg,
pubkey::Pubkey,
program_error::ProgramError,
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct LinkRecord {
pub payer_address: Pubkey,
pub link: String,
}

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug, Default)]
pub struct LinkRecords {
pub records: Vec,
}

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

fn process_instruction(
program_id: &Pubkey,
accounts: &[AccountInfo],
instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
msg!("Instruction: Save Link and Payer Address");

```
let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

let storage_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

let payer_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

if !storage_account.is_writable {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

let link = String::from_utf8(instruction_data.to_vec()).map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?;

let mut records: LinkRecords = match LinkRecords::try_from_slice(&storage_account.data.borrow()) {
    Ok(data) => data,
    Err(_) => LinkRecords::default(),
};

let new_record = LinkRecord {
    payer_address: *payer_account.key,
    link,
};
records.records.push(new_record);
let serialized_data = records.try_to_vec().map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidAccountData)?;
if serialized_data.len() > storage_account.data.borrow_mut().len() {
    return Err(ProgramError::AccountDataTooSmall);
}
storage_account.data.borrow_mut()[..serialized_data.len()].copy_from_slice(&serialized_data);
Ok(())
```

}

This is a sample contract to store address and a link I have created, but after every transaction, the data stored in the state_account is overwritten, I am unable to understand why it happens, Can somebody guide me pls?

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the program writes bytes to the account:

```
storage_account.data.borrow_mut()[..serialized_data.len()].copy_from_slice(&serialized_data);
```

Every single time you call this instruction, `serialized_data` is written into the account, which is why it's updated every time.

Comment: How can I correct it, so the data is not overwritten?

Comment: You can add a check to see if that account has any data. A typical convention is to write an "account discriminator", between 1 and 8 bytes that uniquely identify the account type. In your case, you can write the byte `1` as the first byte in the account. Then during your program, if the first byte in `storage_account` is `1`, you program can return an error. This way an account cannot be overwritten